# Как в ListBox (WPF) добавить иконку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListBox в который выводится список папок и файлов. Как в каждый item добавить маленькую иконку (как в Total Commander например)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
По сути не понимаю ток как добавить эту иконку, а какую именно добавлять уже сам разберусь. Код прикрепил для примера, на всякий, так сказать

```
            listFiles.Items.Clear();
            ListFiles.varListPath = pathDir;
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(pathDir);
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            listFiles.Items.Add("..");
            foreach (DirectoryInfo ListDir in dirs)
                listFiles.Items.Add(ListDir);

            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo ListFiles in files)
                listFiles.Items.Add(ListFiles);
```

Comment: ItemTemplate смотри. [Тут например](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.3.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу сразу на вопрос.
Для подобных вещей создаются стили, которые переопределяют тот или иной элемент.

В нашем случае давайте создадим самый простой ListBox, который будет содержать в себе иконку и название файла:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" MaxWidth="20" MaxHeight="20" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Видно, что мы указали нашему ListBox другой ItemTemplate, который содержит StackPanel с нужными элементами.

Собственно это все.

---

Давайте попробуем теперь заставить это работать.
Для этого нам понадобится некий класс, который будет содержать в себе свойства названия и иконки, ну и для удобства сделаем заполнение этих свойств через конструктор:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel(string name, ImageSource image)
    {
        Name = name;
        Image = image;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь я для теста создам некую коллекцию в которую добавлю все файлы из папки Windows.

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        ImageSource imageSource = null;

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileInfo.FullName);

        if (icon != null)
        {
            using (var bmp = icon.ToBitmap())
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                imageSource = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
            }
        }

        Items.Add(new ItemModel(fileInfo.Name, imageSource));
    }
}
```

Поясню:

- `DataContext = this;` - указываем источник данных для привязки.
- `var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows");` - получаем все файлы из указанной директории.
- `foreach (var file in files)` - проходимся по всем файлам.
- `FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);` - получаем информацию о файле.
- `Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileInfo.FullName);` - получаем иконку файла.
- `using (var bmp = icon.ToBitmap())` - переводим иконку в ImageSource.
- `Items.Add(new ItemModel(fileInfo.Name, imageSource));` - добавляем данные в коллекцию.

Запускаем и любуемся:

[image: Result]

Comment: сори за тупость. А как можно получить имя (строку) выбранного элемента? прост через SelectedItem.ToString() не получается.

Comment: @АртёмГришанович В WPF принято использовать MVVM, а по его правилам из кода знать о View элементах - очень плохо. Нужно делать привязки, к примеру для определения выбранного элемента мы можем привязать у ListBox значение SelectedItem к определенному свойству.

Comment: чет не врубаюсь, надо тип в xaml для ListBox прописать что-то тип такого  <ListBox SelectedItem=" "> ... ?

Comment: @АртёмГришанович Ну создаете свойство в том классе, что указан как DataContext (в моем ответе это прям MainWindow), типом будет то, что находится в ListBox (в моем случае это ItemModel), выходит что то вроде этого `public ItemModel SelectedItem { get; set; }`. Далее в Xaml у ListBox указываем привязку - `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"`. Ну и все, при выделение чего либо в ListBox вы будете получать это значение в привязанном свойстве. Если нужно обратное (из кода задать выделенный элемент), то привязанному свойству надо еще реализовать INPC.