# Как в C# WPF ListView динамически добавить картинку?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Имеется ListView,  как отобразить картинки (.bmp) и название файла, из любой выбранной папки

у меня ListView, а не ListBox
у меня картинки надо отображать , а не иконки к ним

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в ListBox (WPF) добавить иконку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832804/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-listbox-wpf-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Вам лишь остаётся все это применить к ListView и изменить метод добавления изображений.

Comment: С чем конкретно проблемы у вас возникли?

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new  FolderBrowserDialog();
           DialogResult result = folderBrowser.ShowDialog();
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderBrowser.SelectedPath))
           {
                //string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowser.SelectedPath) ;
                textBox1.Text  = folderBrowser.SelectedPath ;

                foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowser.SelectedPath)) {
                    ListView1.Items.Add(item );
                }

            }

Comment: ListView  надо без биндинга, все добавляется динамически

Comment: создать две колонки , одна для картинки другая для текста

Comment: и отобразить саму картинку и название файла,  из выбранной папки

Comment: @vova-forum Без биндинга может вам лучше WinForms использовать? В чем смысл от WPF?

Comment: *все добавляется динамически* – с биндингом и шаблонами как раз вы себе **значительно** облегчите жизнь

Comment: Пытаюсь переделать ListBox, но сам пример не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уважаемый, вот я вам дал пример, где показывается как работать с MVVM, грамотная привязка данных и изменение элемента. Вам лишь оставалось поменять контрол на свой и чуть переписать заполнение данных. Ну раз вы это не смогли сделать, то давайте разбираться...

1. Нам понадобится ViewModel нашего объекта, который будет лежать в коллекции. Что нам нужно в нем? Наверно название и путь. Давайте напишем (не забываем, что привязка осуществляется к **свойствам**, а не *полям*!):

   ```
   public class ImageViewModel
   {
       public ImageViewModel(string name, string path)
       {
           Name = name;
           Path = path;
       }

       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Path { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Далее нам понадобится некая ViewModel, которая будет отвечать за наш основной контент. Что в ней должно быть? Хм, коллекция с нашими объектами и ее заполнение. Пишем:

   ```
   public class MainViewModel
   { 
       public ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel> Images { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ImageViewModel>();

       public MainViewModel()
       {
           var dir = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Images", "*.jpg");
           foreach (var file in dir)
           {
               var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
               Images.Add(new ImageViewModel(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.FullName));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Как тут все работает: Мы объявили пустую `ObservableCollection`, далее я для примера в конструкторе заполняю ее. Сначала мы с помощью `Directory.GetFiles` берем все .jpg файлы в нужной директории (выдаст `string[]`), далее пробегаем по нему циклом, где каждую итерацию мы получаем с помощью `FileInfo` информацию о файле, ну и заносим в нашу коллекцию данные.

3. Привяжем это все, я прям в MainWindow буду писать (вам советую до инициализации окна это делать).

   ```
   private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; } = new MainViewModel();
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = MainViewModel;
   }
   ```
4. Ну и остается View. `ListView` состроит из `GridView`, который содержит в себе `GridViewColumn`. Одну колонку нам трогать не нужно, оставим по стандарту, а вторую переопределим с помощью `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` и добавим туда объект `Image`. Получаем в итоге что то вроде:

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
       <ListView.View>
           <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Название" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
               <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Изображение">
                   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <Image Source="{Binding Path}" MaxHeight="100" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
           </GridView>
       </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
   ```

Все. Запускаем:

[image: Result]

Как по мне с тем вопросом - одно и тоже, но раз не понятно...
В общем, удачи в изучение c#!

Comment: Большущее спасибо