# C# WPF XAML как прописать путь к папке приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как в XAML прописать путь к картинке через Environment.CurrentDirectory

```
<Image Source="file:///"+{Environment.CurrentDirectory}+"/Images/compkeep.png"  />
```

например типа такого как нибудь

Comment: картинки из папки лежит возле .exe ,  как обойтись без ресурсов

Comment: А зачем вам это? Изображений же у вас явно будет больше одного, так храните коллекцию путей. Я же вам [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843737/220553) пример, где из определенной папки берутся все названия + пути, формируется ObservableCollection, к которой мы далее привязываемся...